# Standerd of meta islam

Tags: discussion

Is it me or anyone else start to relies the standard of Meta Islam is getting down. The number of new user and there question are not relevant to meta Islam how we can Improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meta site is really just an extension of the main site, and works pretty much the same way.

How can we improve the standard of the main site?

- Vote to ensure that good content gets promoted over bad content
- Flag content that is irrelevant and/or poisonous to the site
- Edit and/or leave constructive criticism on existing content to improve it
- Post the highest-quality posts we can

So it is on meta.  The only way the meta site will improve is if enough people use it, and actually care enough about using it that they use whatever tools are at their disposal to improve it.

We can't really make people who are uninterested in improving the site participate in meta (and even if we could, we probably don't want to), the best we can do is just make sure our own participation is representative of what we actually want meta to be.